# Windows 8.1 session logoff on RDP disconnect

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-8, windows-8.1, logoff

I installed fresh Win8.1 on a VM, enabled RDP access.

Problem that I'm facing is that when I close RDP client my session and all my windows and applications got closed immediately.
I need session to stay on waiting for me with all my apps running.

I researched on this topic. found an article https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754272.aspx, tried what was suggested, but it didn't help.

I tried to connect from Win8.1 standard RDP client and from microsoft RDP client for iOS. Same behaviour.
User account I use to log in is microsoft account xxx@live.com

P.S. Just in case it matters: VM is virtualbox, virtual box extensions pack is installed on guest 8.1
And I never use 'logoff', i always close RDP client with X. I do this on several other remote machines and it works flawlessly..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop log off when disconnected from RDP session](http://serverfault.com/questions/580916/stop-log-off-when-disconnected-from-rdp-session)

Comment: How many users connect to this VM?

Comment: @austinian only 1 user connected.

Comment: i checked event logs and potentially found a cause, but don't know how to solve this. Each time i disconnect clicking X or writing tsdiscon in console there is a line in event log saying "The Desktop Window Manager has exited with code (0xd00002fe)". i suspect that might be the cause of session being logged off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally!
This problem is solved now.
It looks like Windows 8.1 overriding all the options you set in registry or group policies when it thinks there is not enough RAM.
I had 1Gb RAM on this VM, i increased that to 1.5GB and all the options i set started working! 
The thing is that Windows turns off Fast User Switching in case of 1GB Ram and this influences remote sessions (even there is only 1) in such a weird way.

Thanks everyone.
Anton Viktorov

Answer (score 1):

1 - Close the Remote Desktop Windows with the X, don't close with a logoff.

2 - Set this setting: Computer Configuration --> Administrative Templates --> Windows Components --> Remote Desktop Services --> Remote Desktop Session Host --> Session Time Limits | Enable the "Set time limit for disconnected sessions" >> Never. Watch to be sure no domain GPO overwrite your setting. (By moving the computer from OU)

Comment: I always close with X.
I work on several remote machines - windows servers and windows7 - everything works as expected. But it doesnt work with this 8.1 machine...

Comment: Downvoter, the OP edited is question to answer me.

Comment: @AntonViktorov Domain joined ? Be sure no domain GPO take precedence over the setting you set (Computer Configuration --> Administrative Templates --> Windows Components --> Remote Desktop Services --> Remote Desktop Session Host --> Session Time Limits | Enable the "Set time limit for disconnected sessions" >> Never)

Comment: Downvoted because OP used the term "disconnect" correctly in the title of the post. Edit history was reviewed before downvote. I thought it was clear from the context that the user was using a disconnect method of exiting RDP instead of a logoff method. There are other methods besides "click the x" to do a disconnect, also.

Comment: @austinian Thanks for the feedback. It wasn't clear at first, now it's, as I never assume, but I understand that with the current question I will be downvoted for sure.

Comment: You can always edit, which would give the opportunity for an upvote :)

Comment: this VM machine is not in domain. in group policy i both set Computer and User settings related to timeouts to "Never"

Comment: @AntonViktorov Then try with mstsc /v:IP /admin

Comment: @yagmoth555 nothing new happened. same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Check the group policies related to disconnect time limit.  There are two different ones:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee791756(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Thanks, i already looked into this. I checked that before. I actually edited both "Computer" and "User" policies. I set "never" for timeouts in both branches. Unfortunately this didn't help.