# Remote Desktop: Windows 10 closing programs on disconnect

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I've upgraded one of my systems from Win 7 (32 bit) to Windows 10 (32 bit). I'm using this system as my home server and I only connect to this system via remote desktop connection.

Everything was working perfect on Windows 7. On Win10, when I close the rdp-connection from the top of the screen, I also get this message "Your programs will continue to run while you are disconnected." just like in Win7. I press "OK" and now when I reconnect, all programs are closed and the normal login-procedure is running (loading tray-programs etc.).

I have to re-open all programs again.

I've already checked the session timeout thing via gpedit.msc and made sure, that the session-timeout is set to "Never" but this doesn't change a thing. The programs are also closed, when a short disconnect of a few seconds happens and I'm reconnecting.

Somewhere I have read, that the problem might be because of my low system specs. The system has a Atom processor with 2 cores and only 1 GB of RAM. So, because of the low RAM, the programs will be closed on disconnect.

Is there any way to prevent the system from logging off or close the programs, even with only 1 GB RAM? If not, I might have to downgrade to Win7 again :/

Edit: I'm also using Windows 10 Remote Desktop on a second Server system with a much better CPU and 5 GB RAM. The problem does not exist there. All programs are still opened, when I reconnect to this system.

Comment: Did you also configure it to "disconnect" instead of "end session" *when* never (the timeout) is reached?

Comment: It looks like you've lost your session cookie for Super User. Please [contact Stack Exchange](http://superuser.com/contact) to have your accounts merged and regain control of the question.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you. Accounts are merged now.

Comment: @Yorik: Yes, the timelimit rules are all activated but set to "never". The "Terminate session when time limits are reached" rule is set to "deactivated".

Comment: I think the problem lies somewhere in the "Fast User Switching" service. This will only work, when the system has more than 1 GB ram installed on Windows 8, 8.1 and 10 (see: http://superuser.com/questions/942093/windows-8-1-session-logoff-on-rdp-disconnect ). Does someone know, how to force enable the fast user switching on windows 10? I have found some information for windows xp, but they changed it, so it doesn't work.